# Check if a user likes my page via website

Tags: php, facebook

How do I check if a user who is logged in to my website via the facebook php sdk has liked my page so that I can show him some secret content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the appropriate permissions you can access the [Likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) property of the user: you can then check the returned list to see if your URL is in the list. You can use something like this:

```
$likes = Facebook::api('/me/likes','GET');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using check if `$signed_request->page->liked`:

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }
  if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      echo "This content is for Fans only!";
    } else {
      echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
    }
  }
```

[Detail Here>>](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php/)