# How to detect users on Facebook and show them a message accordingly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our website gets a lot more traction than the facebook page, and I know for sure that more than half the visitors on the website are coming there from referrals by friends (engaging on something their friend liked or shared on facebook). So what I am trying to do here is figure out a way to detect whether someone is using facebook at the time and then detect if they have not already liked our page. The message would be a simple "Like us for more/etc." and a like button.

I looked through several questions but they didn't solve what I am trying to achieve. They require that a user approve the app first.

[How to check if a Facebook user liked an FB page from an external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314519/how-to-check-if-a-facebook-user-liked-an-fb-page-from-an-external-website)

[Check if a user likes my page via website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632719/check-if-a-user-likes-my-page-via-website)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 ways to detect if someone likes a Facebook Page:

- In a page app/tab, with the signed_request parameter, and without authorization of the user (see "getSignedRequest" function in the PHP SDK)
- On an external website ONLY by authorizing the user with the "user_likes" permission first

...and then there are the Social Plugins, you may want to try that one (for example): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Although what you want is just not possible, but you already found out about that ;)

Comment: Thank you Sir, sorry I don't have the credits to give you an upvote.